# ImportError: No module named _ctypes running Python Flask tutorial for Google App Engine on Windows

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm just trying to run the simple hello world app on their tutorials page.  I used to use Google App Engine frequently, but now I can't seem to get it going at all.  I'm on win 10 x64.  Downloaded latest google cloud sdk, and python version 2.7.13

```
> ERROR    2017-01-07 15:25:21,219 wsgi.py:263] Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py",
> line 240, in Handle
>     handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py",
> line 299, in _LoadHandler
>     handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py",
> line 85, in LoadObject
>     obj = __import__(path[0])   File "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\main.py",
> line 18, in <module>
>     from flask import Flask   File "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\lib\flask\__init__.py",
> line 21, in <module>
>     from .app import Flask, Request, Response   File "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\lib\flask\app.py",
> line 27, in <module>
>     from . import json, cli   File "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\lib\flask\cli.py",
> line 17, in <module>
>     import click   File "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\lib\click\__init__.py",
> line 18, in <module> INFO     2017-01-07 10:25:21,229 module.py:806]
> default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>     from .core import Context, BaseCommand, Command, MultiCommand, Group, \   File
> "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\lib\click\core.py", line 8, in <module>
>     from .types import convert_type, IntRange, BOOL   File "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\lib\click\types.py",
> line 4, in <module>
>     from ._compat import open_stream, text_type, filename_to_ui, \   File
> "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\lib\click\_compat.py",
> line 536, in <module>
>     from ._winconsole import _get_windows_console_stream   File "C:\....\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\flask\hello_world\lib\click\_winconsole.py",
> line 16, in <module>
>     import ctypes   File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
>     from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py",
> line 964, in load_module
>     raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname) 
ImportError: No module named _ctypes
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/hello_world    I'm using the command dev_appserver.py app.yaml.  Its the standard Flask sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's sample Flask "Hello World" application requires `Flask 0.11.1`.

This library is not vendored by Google, so developers are required to install it via `pip`

> This sample shows how to use Flask with Google App Engine Standard.
>
> Before running or deploying this application, install the dependencies
>   using pip:
>
> `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`

Flask's `setup.py` [instructs](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.11.1/setup.py) `pip` to install the [click](https://github.com/pallets/click/) library, at a release later than or equal to version 2.0.

```
    install_requires=[
        'Werkzeug>=0.7',
        'Jinja2>=2.4',
        'itsdangerous>=0.21',
        'click>=2.0',
],
```

In November 2015 [a change was committed](https://github.com/pallets/click/commit/bcf8feceb41b3f75f3cd07eb851734fa96cd1991) to `click` to improve support for unicode in the windows console.  This change  added the import of the `ctypes` library which Appengine is choking on, because the Appengine sandbox does not allow importing `ctypes`.

The workaround for this is to overwrite the installed `click` with an earlier version (5.1 [looks like the most recent candidate](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/master/CHANGES)):

`pip install --target lib --upgrade click==5.1`

Answer (score 3):

For me, the workaround mentioned here [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38290292) worked

- goto [sdk_home]\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py
- find the definition of   _WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES = [xxx]
  add following two lines to the list:
  '_winreg',
  '_ctypes',
- try your app again.

The issue was marked fixed on 7/7/2017.