# GAE standard Flask tutorial: ImportError: cannot import name SpooledTemporaryFile

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying the use this [GAE Flask tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env).  I believe I followed it exactly and I downloaded the code from Github so there are no typos.

When I start the dev server (`dev_appserver.py app.yaml`) and go to http://localhost:8080/form, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/.../GIT/TEMP/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
  File "/Users/.../GIT/TEMP/lib/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/Users/.../GIT/TEMP/lib/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/Users/.../GIT/TEMP/lib/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "/Users/.../GIT/TEMP/lib/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 37, in <module>
    from werkzeug.formparser import FormDataParser, default_stream_factory
  File "/Users/.../GIT/TEMP/lib/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
ImportError: cannot import name SpooledTemporaryFile
```

It looks like it has something to do with the GAE sandbox, but I can't figure it out.  I tried running the dev server both inside and outside of the virtualenv.

Is there something special you have to do when using virtualenv with app engine?

Comment: No time to look at it right now, but at a guess it's pulling the latest werkzeug (that import is from a very recent change), so see what version you currently have and `pip install --upgrade` the version before that.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525223/importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-running-python-flask-tutorial-for-google-ap/41531133#41531133 was simialr in principle)

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  Looks like latest werkzeug was released yesterday.  I went back to werkzeug 0.12.2.  Feel free to add an answer when you have time and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tutorial specifies using Flask version 0.12.2.

Flask's [setup.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12.2/setup.py#L74) requires any version of werkzeug after version 0.7

```
install_requires=[
    'Werkzeug>=0.7',
    'Jinja2>=2.4',
    'itsdangerous>=0.21',
    'click>=2.0',
],
```

In werkzeug 0.13, [this commit](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/commit/8eb665a94aea9d9b56371663075818ca2546e152) related to adding support for chunked transfer encoding adds the import of `SpooledTemporaryFile` to `werkzeug.formparser`.

The App Engine sandbox [disables any imports from the `tempfile` module apart from `tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#customized-libraries-in-python-version-27), hence the error.

To workaround this problem, downgrade werkzeug to version 0.12.2, which doesn't include the import.

`pip install --target lib --upgrade werkzeug==0.12.2`

(`pip --upgrade` forces installation of the supplied version, so it will downgrade as well as upgrade)

or amend your vendor requirements file to pin the werkzeug version

```
Flask==0.12.2
werkzeug==0.12.2
```

#### UPDATE:

This issue has now been addressed in both the [Google Samples Docs repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/pull/1266) and [Werkzeug v0.14](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1210).

Comment: I updated werkzeug to 0.14 and the issue is still there, I had to use the solution by Brady Huang (add the 2 statements to appengine_config.py)

Answer (score 4):

I also encounter this error recently.
 
My Python version is 2.7.14 in stand environment.
I believe there is an update few days ago, and interfere this package.

For me, refer to the solution mentioned in Github issue [here](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/281). 
I simply add this to appengine_config.py file:

`import tempfile
tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile = tempfile.TemporaryFile`

Then my project works like charm.
The link also mentioned if you use earlier version of Python 2.7 might solve the problem but I haven't tried the solution.

Comment: I stared having the same problem yesterday, your fix works on the 'cannot import name SpooledTemporaryFile' problem but then I get a problem with 'cannot import name msvcrt'. Its been driving me crazy.

Comment: I found that Flask==0.10.1 and Werkzeug==0.12.2 worked for me, nothing newer worked.