# Google App Engine Standard dev_appserver.py giving a Import Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, werkzeug

I am trying to run `dev_appserver.py` on this [Google App Engine Standard Flask Sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/tutorial)

As the instructions say I run:

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

I should be able to go to `http://localhost:8080/form` but I get `ImportError: No module named msvcrt`.

I found that using `Flask==0.10.1` and `Werkzeug==0.12.2` works but nothing newer.

Versions:

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Python 2.7.14

Google Cloud SDK 182.0.0
app-engine-go
app-engine-python 1.9.63
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.63
bq 2.0.27
core 2017.12.01
gsutil 4.28
```

Comment: There are quite a few issues like this, usually the problem is that Flask or one of its dependencies has added some code that the App Engine sandbox will not permit.  Unless you need a feature in a later version of Flask you may be better off sticking with the versions that you have found to work.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25915535/5320906, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47738001/5320906 and possibly https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531133/5320906.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the example myself from the Cloud Shell, and I also found some issues with the imports. It looks like newer releases of Werkzeug have transferred code to different locations, so as suggested [in this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716196/gae-standard-flask-tutorial-importerror-cannot-import-name-spooledtemporaryfil) if you want to use the example as it is, you should better work with the version 0.12.2 of Werkzeug.

To do so, I recommend you the following steps:

1. Delete the `lib` file in the directory of the application, and all of its content.
2. Edit the `requirements.txt` file to be as follows:

**requirements.txt:**

```
Flask==0.12.2
werkzeug==0.12.2
```

3. Run again the command `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`.

Now you can try running your application locally with the `dev_appserver`. Please make sure that the `appengine_config.py` file is pointing to the proper location of the `lib` folder where the libraries are being installed.

Once you have done all that, everything should be working fine. I have tried browsing for the localhost URL you mentioned and a simple HTML page with a form appears.