# Cross Origin Request Blocked - Create entity GAE datastore

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am following this Google Firebase Tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine

I'm at the last part where it adds the note to the datastore but when I press the button to add the note it doesn't do anything and gives me the following error in Firefox web console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://backend-dot-i7643225firenotes.appspot.com/notes. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Any ideas what causes this? I haven't touched the code Google provided but I'll include it anyway. The rest of it can be found here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes

main.js

```
// Copyright 2016, Google, Inc.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

$(function(){
  // This is the host for the backend.
  // TODO: When running Firenotes locally, set to http://localhost:8081. Before
  // deploying the application to a live production environment, change to
  // https://backend-dot-<PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com as specified in the
  // backend's app.yaml file.
  var backendHostUrl = 'https://backend-dot-i7643225firenotes.appspot.com'; //localhost:8081

  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "REMOVED",
    authDomain: "REMOVED",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  };

  // This is passed into the backend to authenticate the user.
  var userIdToken = null;

  // Firebase log-in
  function configureFirebaseLogin() {

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // [START onAuthStateChanged]
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        $('#logged-out').hide();
        var name = user.displayName;

        /* If the provider gives a display name, use the name for the
        personal welcome message. Otherwise, use the user's email. */
        var welcomeName = name ? name : user.email;

        user.getToken().then(function(idToken) {
          userIdToken = idToken;

          /* Now that the user is authenicated, fetch the notes. */
          fetchNotes();

          $('#user').text(welcomeName);
          $('#logged-in').show();

        });

      } else {
        $('#logged-in').hide();
        $('#logged-out').show();

      }
    // [END onAuthStateChanged]

    });

  }

  // [START configureFirebaseLoginWidget]
  // Firebase log-in widget
  function configureFirebaseLoginWidget() {
    var uiConfig = {
      'signInSuccessUrl': '/',
      'signInOptions': [
        // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,

        //firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        //firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        //firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,

        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ],
      // Terms of service url
      'tosUrl': '<your-tos-url>',
    };

    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
  }
  // [END configureFirebaseLoginWidget]

  // [START fetchNotes]
  // Fetch notes from the backend.
  function fetchNotes() {
    $.ajax(backendHostUrl + '/notes', {
      /* Set header for the XMLHttpRequest to get data from the web server
      associated with userIdToken */
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userIdToken
      }
    }).then(function(data){
      $('#notes-container').empty();
      // Iterate over user data to display user's notes from database.
      data.forEach(function(note){
        $('#notes-container').append($('<p>').text(note.message));
      });
    });
  }
  // [END fetchNotes]

  // [START signOutBtn]
  // Sign out a user
  var signOutBtn =$('#sign-out');
  signOutBtn.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      console.log("Sign out successful");
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
  // [END signOutBtn]

  // [START saveNoteBtn]
  // Save a note to the backend
  var saveNoteBtn = $('#add-note');
  saveNoteBtn.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var noteField = $('#note-content');
    var note = noteField.val();
    noteField.val("");

    /* Send note data to backend, storing in database with existing data
    associated with userIdToken */
    $.ajax(backendHostUrl + '/notes', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userIdToken
      },
      method: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({'message': note}),
      contentType : 'application/json'
    }).then(function(){
      // Refresh notebook display.
      fetchNotes();
    });

  });
  // [END saveNoteBtn]

  configureFirebaseLogin();
  configureFirebaseLoginWidget();

});
```

main.py

```
# Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START app]
import logging

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import flask_cors
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

# Use the App Engine Requests adapter. This makes sure that Requests uses
# URLFetch.
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
HTTP_REQUEST = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

app = Flask(__name__)
flask_cors.CORS(app)


# [START note]
class Note(ndb.Model):
    """NDB model class for a user's note.

    Key is user id from decrypted token.
    """
    friendly_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    message = ndb.TextProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
# [END note]


# [START query_database]
def query_database(user_id):
    """Fetches all notes associated with user_id.

    Notes are ordered them by date created, with most recent note added
    first.
    """
    ancestor_key = ndb.Key(Note, user_id)
    query = Note.query(ancestor=ancestor_key).order(-Note.created)
    notes = query.fetch()

    note_messages = []

    for note in notes:
        note_messages.append({
            'friendly_id': note.friendly_id,
            'message': note.message,
            'created': note.created
        })

    return note_messages
# [END query_database]


# [START list_notes]
@app.route('/notes', methods=['GET'])
def list_notes():
    """Returns a list of notes added by the current Firebase user."""

    # Verify Firebase auth.
    # [START verify_token]
    id_token = request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ').pop()
    claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(
        id_token, HTTP_REQUEST)
    if not claims:
        return 'Unauthorized', 401
    # [END verify_token]

    notes = query_database(claims['sub'])

    return jsonify(notes)
# [END list_notes]


# [START add_note]
@app.route('/notes', methods=['POST', 'PUT'])
def add_note():
    """
    Adds a note to the user's notebook. The request should be in this format:

        {
            "message": "note message."
        }
    """

    # Verify Firebase auth.
    id_token = request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ').pop()
    claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(
        id_token, HTTP_REQUEST)
    if not claims:
        return 'Unauthorized', 401

    # [START create_entity]


    data = request.get_json()

    # Populates note properties according to the model,
    # with the user ID as the key name.
    note = Note(
        parent=ndb.Key(Note, claims['sub']),
        message=data['message'])

    # Some providers do not provide one of these so either can be used.
    note.friendly_id = claims.get('name', claims.get('email', 'Unknown'))
    # [END create_entity]

    # Stores note in database.
    note.put()

    return 'OK', 200
# [END add_note]


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    # Log the error and stacktrace.
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return 'An internal error occurred.', 500
# [END app]
```

Comment: Where are the CORS headers in the .py file?

Comment: I am not sure what those are? Do I need to include this? This is Google's own code so not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31643606/492258)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried [the tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine) myself, and everything worked fine for me, so I guess you might have either skipped some step or you have some wrong configuration.

The only notable differences I see between your example and mine, are the following, so you can try modifying them in order to see if your issue gets solved:

- I saw some `import error` in my code, so I added this line `werkzeug==0.12.2` to the `backend/requirements.txt` file, which includes the libraries that will be installed. The latest releases of the `werzeug` library have moved some dependencies to nested folders, reason why some imports were failing (you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788484/google-app-engine-standard-dev-appserver-py-giving-a-import-error/47791541#47791541)). Then, remove the `lib` folder and rerun the command to install the libraries `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`. Before doing this modification, I had the same problem as yours, nothing happened when clicking on the *Save* button in my application, but after the change, it worked fine.
- The `config` variable in my `frontend/main.js` file has some additional field which you have removed. I got the parameters following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) and going to my Firebase console, clicking in the round *Add Firebase to your web app* button, and copying the content as follows:

**`config` variable in `frontend/main.js`:**

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SOME_ID>"
  };
```

As for the rest, everything looks fine to me, only that I have just tried using `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID` and I have removed all the rest. I am also running the application in production (App Engine Standard), not using the local Development Server. I had a look at my CORS configuration too, and I have nothing special, only the couple of lines you already have in your code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
flask_cors.CORS(app)
```

You should try with the couple of suggestions I provided, and come back with more information about the error if it keeps coming up.