# Python-Jose with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jwt, python-jose

I am trying to get [python-jose](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose) to work with Google App Engine.

As soon as I add `from jose import jwt` I get an error `ImportError: No module named Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom`

In the `README.rst` it says:

> This is a JOSE implementation that is fully compatible with Google App Engine which requires the use of the PyCrypto library.

I am guessing `dev_appserver.py` has blocked the file `lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/winrandom.pyd` as its not pure Python.

[GAE Python runtime environment must be pure Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_Pure_Python)

Is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: I'd imagine this is specific to the dev server on Windows, so whitelisting `winrandom.pyd` might work, as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091630/5320906